# A nuts and bolts reference to C# performance and memory use

Tags: c#

I wonder if anyone could point me in the direction where I can read about the nuts and bolts of C#. What I'm interested in learning are method call costs, what it costs to create objects and such.

My aim of learning this is to get a better understanding of how increase the performance of an application and get a better understanding of how the C# language works.

The reference should preferable be a **book**, a book that I can read cover to cover.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) is excellent for low level details about the CLR. It specifically covers the details of method invocation, creating new objects, garbage collection and lots more.

For actual performance numbers you should use a profiler to avoid the common pitfalls of premature optimization.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the suggestion to profile. I remember having to go through 1000's of line of code removing the conditionals because the original programmer has assumed comparing arguments against zero cost less than the floating point multiply they 'optimised away'.

Comment: I'm actually using (learning to use) the built in visual studio profiler and it hit me when I was using it that I want to learn more about the things specified in my question.

Comment: @Phil: Well, the book will tell you all that and more. Also, Joe Duffy's .NET Framework book is also worth a read, but it has not been updated for the new runtime (AFAIK).

Comment: I have read a little about the book now and I have decided to order it. I'm thinking about buying C# in depth as well.

Comment: @Phil C# in depth is another great book.

Answer (score 1):

For performance profiling existing code, have a look at [Eqatec Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler). (There is a free license for personal use).

Comment: In fact, EQATEC Profiler is now completely free even for all uses, both personal and commercial.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to know about [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) and [CLR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)